# Adding duplicate columns of a txt file to a list in Java

Tags: java, list, text-files

I have a very large txt file where some columns do not appear on every row so I decided to collect the columns in a list. Here is a sample of how the txt file rows look like.

> 35=d|5799=00000000|980=A|779=20190721173046000465|1180=310|1300=64|462=5|207=XCME|1151=ES|6937=ES|55=ESM0|48=163235|22=8|167=FUT|461=FFIXSX|200=202006|15=USD|1142=F|562=1|1140=3000|969=25.000000000|9787=0.010000000|996=IPNT|1147=50.000000000|1150=302775.000000000|731=00000110|5796=20190724|1149=315600.000000000|1148=285500.000000000|1143=600.000000000|1146=12.500000000|9779=N|864=2|865=5|1145=20190315133000000000|865=7|1145=20200619133000000000|1141=1|1022=GBX|264=10|870=1|871=24|872=00000000000001000010000000001111|1234=0|5791=279|5792=10121|
>
> 35=d|5799=00000000|980=A|779=20190721173046000465|1180=310|1300=64|462=5|207=XCME|1151=ES|6937=ES|55=ESU9|48=191262|22=8|167=FUT|461=FFIXSX|200=201909|15=USD|1142=F|562=1|1140=3000|969=25.000000000|9787=0.010000000|996=IPNT|1147=50.000000000|1150=302150.000000000|731=00000110|5796=20190724|1149=315700.000000000|1148=285600.000000000|1143=600.000000000|1146=12.500000000|9779=N|864=2|865=5|1145=20180615133000000000|865=7|1145=20190920133000000000|1141=1|1022=GBX|264=10|870=1|871=24|872=00000000000001000010000000001111|1234=0|5791=250519|5792=452402|
>
> 35=d|5799=00000000|980=A|779=20190721173046000465|1180=310|1300=64|462=5|207=XCME|1151=$E|6937=0ES|55=0ESQ9|48=229588|22=8|167=FUT|461=FFIXSX|200=201908|15=USD|1142=F|562=1|1140=3000|969=25.000000000|9787=0.010000000|996=IPNT|1147=50.000000000|1150=25.000000000|731=00000011|5796=20190607|1143=0.000000000|1146=12.500000000|9779=N|864=2|865=5|1145=20190621133000000000|865=7|1145=20190816133000000000|1141=1|1022=GBX|264=10|870=1|871=24|872=00000000000001000010000000001111|1234=0|
>
> 35=d|5799=00000000|980=A|779=20190721173114000729|1180=441|1300=56|462=16|207=DUMX|1151=1O|6937=OQE|55=OQEH4 C6100|48=1546|22=8|167=OOF|461=OCEFPS|***201=1***|200=202403|15=USD|202=6100.000000000|947=USD|9850=0.100000000|1142=F|562=1|1140=999|969=1.000000000|1146=10.000000000|9787=0.010000000|996=BBL|1147=1000.000000000|731=00000001|1148=0.100000000|9779=N|5796=20190718|864=2|865=5|1145=20181031213000000000|865=7|1145=20240126193000000000|1141=1|1022=GBX|264=3|870=1|871=24|872=00000000000001000000000100000101|1234=1|1093=4|1231=1.0000|711=1|309=211120|305=8|311=OQDH4|1647=0|
>
> 35=d|5799=00000000|980=A|779=20190721173115000229|1180=441|1300=56|462=16|207=DUMX|1151=1O|6937=OQE|55=OQEM4 C5700|48=2053|22=8|167=OOF|461=OCEFPS|***201=1***|200=202406|15=USD|202=5700.000000000|***201=4***|947=USD|9850=0.100000000|1142=F|562=1|1140=999|969=1.000000000|1146=10.000000000|9787=0.010000000|996=BBL|1147=1000.000000000|731=00000001|1148=0.100000000|9779=N|5796=20190718|864=2|865=5|1145=20181031213000000000|865=7|1145=20240425183000000000|1141=1|1022=GBX|264=3|870=1|871=24|872=00000000000001000000000100000101|1234=1|1093=4|1231=1.0000|711=1|309=329748|305=8|311=OQDM4|1647=0|

In the sample above for example the column `201=…` does not appear in the first three rows but it appears in the fourth and fifth row. So I decided to collect the columns in a list but I did not consider that a column could appear more than one or two times but my method works only for that since at first I thought it could appear max. twice. What can I change so that it adds the column more than once or twice?

EDIT: in the last row there appears `201=…` twice and I want to add that too in my list.

```
private static void appendNewColumns(List<String> rows, List<String> columns) {
    for (String row : rows) {
        String[] splittedRow = row.split("\\|");
        for (String column : splittedRow) {
            String[] entry = column.split("=");
            if (columns.contains(entry[0])) {
                continue;
            }
            columns.add(entry[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to add a column more than once, why do you need the if statement:             if (columns.contains(entry[0])) {
                continue;
            }

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to do here and what doesn't work.Your code collects all column names without duplicates. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran because not every column of every row should be added since then I would have redundant columns, I just want to add the new ones. The problem of my solution is that this works only for the second time it appears

Comment: @Amongalen sorry I did not explain it good enough. I want to add all columns, the duplicates as well, I have edited the question, I hope this makes it clearer

Comment: @SilverFullbuster I am a little confused. What is your approach to handle duplicates? a. add the duplicate to the list b. remove existing column and add new column?

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran a: add the duplicate to the list

Comment: I think I finally understand your problem. However, what interests me is what you want to do with that list. The problem looks really weird to me, you won't be able distinguish between two of the same column anyway.

Comment: @Amongalen I think it is possible to distinguish between them by using a MultiMap. In the end I want to output a txt file which contains all columns with their data and in the rows where that column does not appear it should contain `null` and this works for me now but I forgot to consider that a column could appear more than once or twice

Comment: I bet there could be some edge cases in which you won't be able to tell where to put `null`s. Lets take the 4th row and remove 3 values after the `201` column, that is columns `200`, `15` and `202`. Do you assign the value from `201` in the source to the first or the second of the `201` columns in your output table?

Comment: This is not my complete code. I have another method which ensures that it assigns the values to the right column since I have a list for duplicates there. I have already tested it. This method is only for adding the columns to a list

Answer (score 0):

If you need to record all occurrences regardless of duplication, you need to omit the if statement.

```
if (columns.contains(entry[0])) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: That solution won't work if I understand the problem correctly. OP wants to get a list of all "different" columns. From his example `201` is meant to appear exactly twice because it appears maximum of 2 times, in the 5th row, means those are two "different" columns. If it were to appear 1 more time in the 6th row it would still only appear twice in the list. That is my interpretation of the OPs question.

Comment: @Amongalen exactly!